# Is it possible to fully install a driver when the device is not present?

Tags: windows, installation, driver, wdf

Is it possible to fully install (and not just pre-install) a device driver on a system before the physical device is plugged in? In particular, I'm looking at the [D2XX drivers by FTDI](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm). Their driver installation program effectively runs dpinst.exe, and if you watch the console output of that program it says this:

> No matching device was found for 'c:\drivers\ftdiport.inf'. Driver will be installed when plugged in.

The trouble is that I'm also using their .NET library for accessing the device, and that library is funny. It pops up an alert in the constructor if the driver isn't installed. Of course the usual solution is to simply plug in the device and let the driver installation finish as normal, but sometimes this is neglected. The pitfalls with having an unavoidable popup box in a 3rd party library should be obvious.

So does anyone know of a way to automate the full installation, and not just the pre-installation? Are there any dangers to copying the driver to the system folder manually / in advance?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to mention "fully install" by "staging" the driver not by "loading" the driver.  You can refer to the source code of "devcon.exe" for dp_add command, which actually do staging the driver package. Staged driver package will be being searched by PnP Manager when the unknown device is detected.